# numpy sort acting weirdly when sorting on a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, numpy, dataframe

When I do a `data[genres].sum()` I get the following result

```
Action        1891
Adult            9
Adventure     1313
Animation      314
Biography      394
Comedy        3922
Crime         1867
Drama         5697
Family         754
Fantasy        916
Film-Noir       40
History        358
Horror        1215
Music          371
Musical        260
Mystery       1009
News             1
Reality-TV       1
Romance       2441
Sci-Fi         897
Sport          288
Thriller      2832
War            512
Western        235
dtype: int64
```

But when I try to sort on the sum using `np.sort`

```
genre_count = np.sort(data[genres].sum())[::-1]
pd.DataFrame({'Genre Count': genre_count})`
```

I get the following result

```
`Out[19]:
    Genre Count
0   5697
1   3922
2   2832
3   2441
4   1891
5   1867
6   1313
7   1215
8   1009
9   916
10  897
11  754
12  512
13  394
14  371
15  358
16  314
17  288
18  260
19  235
20  40
21  9
22  1
23  1
```

The expected result should be like this:

```
Genre Count
Drama   5697
Comedy  3922
Thriller    2832
Romance     2441
Action  1891
Crime   1867
Adventure   1313
Horror  1215
Mystery     1009
Fantasy     916
Sci-Fi  897
Family  754
War     512
Biography   394
Music   371
History     358
Animation   314
Sport   288
Musical     260
Western     235
Film-Noir   40
Adult   9
News    1
Reality-TV  1
```

It seems like numpy is ignoring the genre column.

Could somebody help me understand where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`data[genres].sum()` returns a Series. The genre column isn't actually a column - it's an index.

`np.sort` just looks at the values of the DataFrame or Series, *not* at the index, and it returns a new NumPy array with the sorted `data[genres].sum()` values. The index information is lost.

The way to sort `data[genres].sum()` and keep the index information would be to do something like:

```
genre_count = data[genres].sum()
genre_count.sort(ascending=False) # in-place sort of genre_count, high to low
```

You can then turn the sorted `genre_count` Series back into a DataFrame if you like:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Genre Count': genre_count})
```

Answer (score 1):

`data[genres].sum()` returns a Series.

And if you're using pandas version 0.2, the command have little bit changes.

```
    genre_count = data[genres].sum()
    genre_count.sort_values(ascending=False)`
```

You could find reference on [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html#pandas.Series.sort_values)